# Vertical scrollbar position in a table

Tags: javascript

I need your help.

The following javascript coding, that works flawlessly when it is executed, however, the coding starts off the scroll position to the bottom of my data table.

How can the javascript coding be modified so as to start at the top instead?

```
var table = document.getElementById("data");
var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

if (table.parentNode.scrollTop + table.parentNode.offsetHeight - rows[0].offsetHeight < rows[i].offsetTop + rows[i].offsetHeight || rows[i].offsetTop < table.parentNode.scrollTop + rows[0].offsetHeight) {
table.parentNode.scrollTop = rows[i].offsetTop - table.parentNode.offsetHeight / 2;
}
```

Comment: no one will easily read such code, please edit your question a bit, maybe add comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rows[i].offsetTop` should be `rows[0].offsetTop`

Answer (score 0):

I changed the `rows[i]` that grabs the row from a seperate nested function and changed it to `row`